# Correct way to close QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I recently changed from tkinter to Pyqt5 as I'm developing a semi-large application in Python 3.7.8

Every time I had to close windows I used the method `self.destroy()`, and there was a small chance that, when I closed all the program and having no windows, the interpreter was still running and I needed to terminate the process manually, even when using `sys.exit(app.exec_())`

I could had the program running for 15 seconds or 30 minutes, it was completely random.

I just saw another method that is called `self.close()`, so I replaced the `self.destroy()` with it, but I'm not sure if this is the intended practice or if there is a better way. I still have to check if the problem doesn't appear again.

It's better to use `self.destroy` or `self.close` for pyqt5 applications?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`close()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close):

> Closes this widget.

[`destroy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#destroy):

> Frees up window system resources.
> [...]
> This function is usually called from the QWidget destructor.

If you `close()` the widget, it can be opened/shown again later if required, *but* if the widget is a top level window *and* is the last visible one, Qt will automatically quit the application (assuming the QApplication has the [`quitOnLastWindowClosed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) set, which is the default behavior). In this case PyQt will automatically destroy the window and free up memory, meaning that `destroy()` will be called anyway.

Note that the window will also be automatically destroyed when closed if it has no other reference or parent: as much as any other python object, the garbage collector will *delete* the widget and its children, which causes a call to the QWidget destroyer.

So, you should always call `close()`, since it ensures that Qt follows the correct steps: send a QCloseEvent (which could be ignored, if required) and notify the application about that, so that it can actually quit if the window was the last one.