# How to return from a Qdialog window

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have the following code to create an "About" windows

```
class Ui_aboutWindow(QDialog):
    def setupUi(self, aboutWindow):
        aboutWindow.setObjectName("aboutWindow")
        aboutWindow.setEnabled(True)
        aboutWindow.resize(330, 300)
        aboutWindow.setWindowTitle("About")
        #aboutWindow.setWhatsThis("")

        self.aboutText = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(aboutWindow)
        self.aboutText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 280, 190))
        #self.aboutText.setWhatsThis("")
        self.aboutText.setAcceptRichText(False)
        self.aboutText.setObjectName("aboutText")

        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(aboutWindow)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 240, 281, 41))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.btSysinfo = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.btSysinfo.setText("SysInfo")
        self.btSysinfo.setObjectName("btSysinfo")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btSysinfo)

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)

        self.btOK = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.btOK.setToolTip("")
        self.btOK.setWhatsThis("")
        self.btOK.setText("OK")
        self.btOK.setShortcut("")
        self.btOK.setObjectName("btOK")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btOK)

        # connect buttons to signal
        self.btOK.clicked.connect(self.return_ok)
        self.btSysinfo.clicked.connect(self.sysinfo)

    def return_ok(self):
            print("OK clicked")
            self.destroy()
            return

    def sysinfo(self):
            print("sysinfo clicked")
            pass
```

I call this from the main window like this

```
def aboutActionProcedure(self):
    # print("Opening a new popup window...")
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Ui_aboutWindow()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
```

the OK button in the about window calls the return_ok routine (verified with print statement), but the about window does not close

I do not want to use a Qmessagebox, as i want to add another nonstandard button to the window (sysInfo button)

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems and misconceptions in your code.

First of all, you are *not* using your `Ui_aboutWindow` subclass, or, at least, you're not using it as you might think.
I'm under the impression that you're trying to mimic the behavior of files generated by `pyuic`, which is something that should be avoided: `pyuic` files are written as "interface layers" to build the GUI from ui files, but if you are going to create it manually you should just subclass QWidgets (or, QDialog, in your case) without using `setupUi` like that.

The problem is that using `setupUi` with the new QDialog instance you created, the `self` in the `return_ok` and `sysinfo` functions actually refers to the `Ui_aboutWindow` instance you created, but what you're actually showing and "setting up" is the `dialog` instance of `QDialog` created in the `aboutActionProcedure` function. So, `destroy` will actually try to destroy the `Ui_aboutWindow` instance (which was never shown).

Other notes and issues:

- a layout manager should always be set for the top level widget;
- you *can* use a QMessageBox even if you need a custom button: just use [`addButton()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#addButton);
- you can use a [QDialogButttonBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html) for dialog buttons and, just like the message box, add a custom button using [`addButton()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#addButton) with a specific role (for custom uses, `ActionRole` might be the best choice);
- `destroy()` is not the right method to close a window, use `close()` instead (read more about [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62912374/2001654));
- to correctly return a QDialog that has been `exec`uted, you should not call `close`, but use one of the existing functions instead: [`accept()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept), [`reject()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#reject), or [`done(r)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#done);

Here's a much simpler and cleaner way to achieve what you want:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class AboutWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.resize(330, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("About")

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.aboutText = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        self.aboutText.setAcceptRichText(False)
        layout.addWidget(self.aboutText)

        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.btSysinfo = QtWidgets.QPushButton("SysInfo")
        self.buttonBox.addButton(self.btSysinfo, QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)

        self.btSysinfo.clicked.connect(self.sysinfo)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.return_ok)
        # note that, if you don't need to do anything specific, you can also do this:
        # self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)

    def return_ok(self):
        print("OK clicked")
        # set the dialog as "accepted" and return its exec()
        self.accept()

    def sysinfo(self):
        print("sysinfo clicked")


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('About...')
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.aboutActionProcedure)

    def aboutActionProcedure(self):
        # print("Opening a new popup window...")
        dialog = AboutWindow()
        dialog.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such an educational answer. It cleared up a number of things in my mind that i was struggling with. With this help i got past the hurdle, and can soldier on. Much obliged.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your issue, you can mark it as "Accepted" by clicking on the check mark on the left (this will increase reputation too).

Comment: i noticed this centers the window on the screen. How would i go about centering this in the parent (or calling) window.  it seems this about window has parent None.

Comment: UPDATE: i got it, dialog = AboutWindow(self) did the trick